# Error loading R package - libicui18n.so.68: cannot open shared object file

Tags: r, archlinux

Until yesterday, I could run `library(car)` just fine. But after running `yay -Syyu` and upgrading as many packages as I can, this no longer works.

```
> library(car)
Loading required package: carData
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/my-name/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.68: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am running this on Arch Linux.

Comment: Can you try to resintall `stringi` `install.packages('stringi')`

Comment: If `install.packages("stringi")` doesn't fix it, perhaps `update.packages()` will (per https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=232251)

Comment: @akrun That worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can install the 'stringi' package

```
install.packages('stringi')
```

Comment: In my case I had the `stringi` installed but it was build/installed before the recent update of my OS. So all I needed to to was to reinstall the `stringi` package. just running `install.packages('stringi')`.

Comment: This does indeed resolve the issue. Perhaps worth mentioning is that I had to run "vanilla" R (not Radian) as root for it to work.

Comment: Ok so now I got the error message above again. Only this time I get it whentry